# Nconf install not detecting perl

Tags: monitoring, ubuntu-12.04, nagios

During my Nconf install I get

Requirements

PHP 5.0 (or higher) -> 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4    OK
MySQL 5.0.2 (or higher) -> 5.5.24           OK
PHP-MySQL support                           OK
Perl 5.6 (or higher) ->                     FAILED

But when I check

```
perl -v
```

This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way install.php gets the version :

Take a look at **INSTALL.php**

```
function find_PERL_Version() { (line 316)
        $output = shell_exec('perl -v');
       [...]
        preg_match('/is perl, v([0-9]+[\.0-9]*)/i', $output, $version);
```

This script is expecting this kind of syntax :

> 'This is perl, v5.nn.mm' (eg v5.10.0).

Your perl application returns

> 'This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2)'

A possible workaround (based on your configuration) is to replace the preg_match :

> `preg_match('/v([0-9]+[\.0-9]*)/i', $output, $version);`

Function will then return the correct version (5.14.2) and you will be able to continue the install.